# Replacement rate question

Tags: forecasting

I have a model for the size of the installed base of a certain item.  I know that on average any item will be replaced every 10 years, lets say.

How can I calculate the number of items each year that will be replaced?

Comment: Replacement rate for 10 years is 1. What is replacement rate for 20 years? What is replacement rate for one year?

Comment: I am not sure how this is a forecasting(that is time series question). I think to answer this you need more than an average. You need to have some probability of each item being replaced each year.